# Not able to access blazor website from other computers

Tags: iis, blazor, web-hosting

I am trying to host a Blazor website on a local Windows machine via IIS, and it can be accessed from the same machine using IP address in the URL like https://10.0.0.123:8080/myblazor, and I also make sure port 8080 is opened on the firewall, but I am not able to access my Blazor website using the same URL from other computers. Does anyone know why? Thanks in advance!

I added another regular website (simple HTML website) and I can access from other computers. So doesn't look like it's the firewall issue or IIS issue.

Comment: blazor server or webassembly? do you use an updated browser on another computers?

Comment: Did you install url rewriter and ms bundle config on iis?

Comment: Enable FRT to see if the HTTP requests from the other computers land on IIS properly, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing

Comment: it's blazor server. the broswer version is the same on the web server and on the other computers. and I tried both Chrome and Edge. thanks.

Comment: I don't know what I did, after taking a long nap, it's working now, I can access my blazor website from outside the web server now. I did add the FRT to IIS, but it didn't catch any errors. Thanks for all the advices!